# Process huge data and write to file for client to download

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, web

I have got a situation which require to Select data from database (MS SQL), then process the data a little before provide it to client to download. The problem is that the table contains a HUGE number of records to select (~1 Billion records). (EXPORT function)

Currently, I got 2 issues:

1. Select data -> SQL Server response too slow, usually hanged
2. I used streambuilder to store content of file before write to file for client to download. So, with huge data, IIS got problem with memory -> HANGED.

I have been trying some solutions to deal with them, I appreciate any advices from you for the good solution to deal with huge data in this case.

---

My thinking of solution for :
1st issue: select data like paging, get around 10000 record per time.
2nd: try to create a temporary file on server, write data to that file, and send to client after all data is available in that file.
In your professional experience, are these solutions possible?

Comment: You have number of completely unrelated issues. For selecting google indices and query optimization. for getting it into file better use sqlbulkload. google iis streaming for issues with big files.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi Vittore, thanks for your comment. About "for getting it into file better use sqlbulkload", I have made a quick investigation on sqlbulkload, and got no clue how it help to make better getting into file? could you provide me a little more detail on that?

Comment: Having a `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` which involves a table scan will cause the server to overload. So you might first examine your query and issue a `SELECT TOP 10000`.